# Column comparison with varying id's

Tags: r

I have the following variables

```
id1 = c(1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5)

id2 = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4)

digit1 = c(243, 888, 343, 276, 493, 024, 305, 093)

digit2 = c(343, 756, 947, 089, 390, 930, 024)

df1 = data.frame(id1, digit1)

df2 = data.frame(id2, digit2)
```

I'm looking to find a way to see how many matches digits1 has with digits2 based on similar id's. The frequency for a given id can vary within the same data frame and also when compared with the other data frame.

I don't want it to count an extra incorrect or correct if id1 has more frequency than id2 for a given id. For example when comparing the first three digits in df1 with only the first two digit in df2 the returning vector would count that  as 1 correct , 1 incorrect, and 1 NA. I'm trying to merge both data frames and add the new column for the outcomes of the matching.

After aligning the the column in df1 and df2 and merging into a new data frame,  I want to add a vector like (0, NA, 1,  0, 0, 1, NA, NA) to the new data frame.

The actual data that I'll be using has thousands of rows for each dataframe

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be by joining the two data frames and then checking which ids have `digit1 = digit2`, here's what I mean:

```
# Data from the question (before the edit)
id1 = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7)
id2 = c(1,2,2,3,3,4,5)
digit1 = c(243, 343, 276, 493, 024, 305, 093, 393, 208)
digit2 = c(343, 947, 089, 390, 930, 024, 093)
df1 = data.frame(id1, digit1)
df2 = data.frame(id2, digit2)

library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = c('id1'='id2')) %>% 
  mutate(match = (digit1 == digit2)) %>% 
  group_by(id1) %>% 
  summarise(match = sum(match))
```

you get:

```
#     id1  match
#    <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     1
# 2     2     0
# 3     3     0
# 4     4     1
# 5     5     1
# 6     6    NA
# 7     7    NA
```

Comment: The only problem iwth this is that I couldn't know if an Incorrect happened if there were at least two of the same id's in both data frames.

Comment: I saw your edited question, and I don't quite get the end result you want, what does the `NA` indicate here?